# Discord Bot Only Responds To Private Messages Instead Of A Server

Tags: discord, bots

I'm attempting to figure out why my discord bot won't function in my discord server because I am not sure if there is anything wrong with the written code. The commands always function when they are delivered straight to the Discord bot, however when I try to add the bot to the server, they don't appear to function.

Responses.py

---

```
import random
def handle_respsonse(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    

    if p_message == 'hello':
        return 'hi'
   
    return "I do not understand, type: hello"
```

Bot.py

---

```
import discord
import responses

async def send_message(message,user_message,is_private):
    try:
        response = responses.handle_respsonse(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = #Discord Bot Token
    client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')


    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)

        print(f'{username} said: {user_message} ({channel})')

        if user_message[0] == '?':
            user_message = user_message[1:]
            await send_message(message,user_message,is_private=True)
        else:
            await send_message(message,user_message,is_private=False)


    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few additional things by going to the Discord developers page and turning on "messages intent". I altered how the "def run_discord_bot()" function's intentions operated. It worked after.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you have enabled the `guild_messages` intent when creating your client.

```py
import discord
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Never mind I figured out the problem, I had to go to the discord developers website and needed to turn on messages intent on.